# Is RadStyleSheetManager only for Telerik Controls CSS or can it be used to combine all CSS for a site?

Tags: asp.net, css, telerik

Is RadStyleSheetManager only for Telerik Controls CSS or can it be used to combine all CSS for a site?

I'm a little confused because the description on Telerik's site states:

> By default each of the RadControls for
>   ASP.NET Ajax serves a set of files
>   (stylesheets) needed for its proper
>   client-side look.

Should I be able to use my own CSS stylesheets in there and have them be combined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the RadStyleSheetManager for your own stylesheets.  There are two ways of doing this depending on whether your stylesheet is an [embedded resource](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radstylesheetmanager.html) or just a [file on your webserver](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/scriptmanager-and-stylesheetmanager/radstylesheetmanager-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object.aspx).

Note with option 2 you have to add a key to your application settings object like so:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Telerik.Web.UI.StyleSheetFolders" value="/style/,/RadControls/" />
</appSettings>
```

Once registered with the RadStyleSheetManager, your css files will be combined with whatever other stylesheets the manager is serving up

Comment: I've found that I need to use a semicolon instead of a comma to separate the folder names:  `value="/style/;/RadControls/"`